# nginx wont restart - errors

Tags: nginx, configuration

after trying **nginx -t**
and service **nginx restart** or **nginx -s** **reaload** I have found fallowing errors. Any idea how to fix them? Thank you for answers.

> nm@srv:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ nginx -s reload
>       nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
>       2015/08/03 09:12:35 [warn] 13513#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
>       2015/08/03 09:12:35 [warn] 13513#0: conflicting server name "venusfactorfreetrial.sandbox.modpreneur.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
>       2015/08/03 09:12:35 [notice] 13513#0: signal process started
>       2015/08/03 09:12:35 [alert] 13513#0: kill(1031, 1) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
>
> nm@srv:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ nginx -t
>       nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
>       2015/08/03 09:16:02 [warn] 13565#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
>       2015/08/03 09:16:02 [warn] 13565#0: conflicting server name "venusfactorfreetrial.sandbox.modpreneur.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
>       nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>       2015/08/03 09:16:02 [emerg] 13565#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
>       nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Lol I am stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `sudo service nginx reload`